# Python: downloading xml files in batch returns a damaged zip file

Tags: python, xml, windows, batch-file, urllib2

Drawing inspiration [from this post](https://dzone.com/articles/how-download-file-python), I am trying to download a bunch of `xml` files in batch from a website:

```
import urllib2

url='http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/'

f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
with open("C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\data.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)
```

The `zip` file is created within seconds, but as I attempt to access it, an error window comes up:

```
Windows cannot open the folder.
The Compressed (zipped) Folder "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\data.zip" is invalid.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not opening file handles inside the zip file:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zipfile

url='http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/'

fileurls = []

f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
mainpage = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(mainpage, 'html.parser')

tablewrapper = soup.find(id='openDataStatic')

for table in tablewrapper.find_all('table'):
    for link in table.find_all('a'):
        fileurls.append(link['href'])

with zipfile.ZipFile("data.zip", "w") as code:
    for url in fileurls:
        print('Downloading: %s' % url)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = f.read()
        xmlfilename = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        code.writestr(xmlfilename, data)
```

Comment: I reckon a few typos: (`filesnames`/`filenames`), and then `filename` in `f` inside the for loop, which should be `xmlfile` I guess. However, this returned an empty `zip` file.

Comment: you're correct, sorry i changed approach while typing it out, missed those bits, and how did you get the list of filenames? when i looked at the link you gave it gives a html page, you need to get a list of the xml files you want to download first

Comment: Exactly! I did not immediately get from your answer that `filenames` needs to be populated *first* LOL

Comment: made a few changes, so you now have an example of how to use a html parser (beautifulsoup4) to parse the website and find the links, then download and save each into the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing to encode this as zip file. If instead you choose to open it in a plain text editor such as notepad it should show you the raw xml.

Comment: But a plain text file in this case would contain *all* the `xml` files hosted by the website. That's over 200 files put together.

Comment: looking at the request data what returns is actually the html that makes up the page. If you are looking to parse this page and then download the xml files I would suggest looking at beautiful soup. There is a tutorial on how to use it [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python).

This should allow you to extract the references to each of the files.